UID auto adjustment in Bitnami containers
I wonder how Bitnami ccreated containers able to change the ownership of directories in containers to always match Security Context Constraint in OpenShift environment. For example each Openshift project requires to match certain high UID range in order to run container at all. For example Bitnami containers is able to reassing all permissions from UID 1001 to 1000680000.
I've been trying to catch their container build process for a while but I could not find the mechanism responsible for it. This is the repo I was basing on
https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/postgresql/16/debian-12

I think it is not included in the build process. It is coming from the OpenShift.
https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/a-guide-to-openshift-and-uids
